# I want to combine a NOT NULL string result from a function with a field(s) that can be NULL from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, parameters, null, stored-functions

Ok, I have this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReaderSearcher(id INT) RETURNS varchar(100) NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE resultList varchar(100);
    IF id > 0 THEN
        SET result = 'The search was a success! Readers:';
    ELSE
        SET result = 'The parameter has to be bigger than "0"!';
    END IF;
    RETURN result;
END $$
```

and this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searcher(id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT ReaderSearcher(id) AS RESULT, readers.firstname AS NAME
    FROM readers WHERE READER_ID = id;
END $$
```

and I want my results to be:

1) one column which is not null and contains at least the message 'The parameter has to be bigger than "0"!'

2) two columns, first has the message about the result and the second that has name of the reader or some kind of placeholder.

So far it works if the parameter is bigger than 0 but anything lower gives me nothing, just columns' labels. How can I make it work? I tried some stuff like COALESCE and CONCAT with ISNULL but it stays the same.

edit: I'm using MySQL and MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Comment: @OcasoProtal MySQL

Comment: Can you edit and share us the desired output?

Comment: @James I posted my answer, the desired output was at least one record, be it the error message or just an actual name of the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the answer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReaderSearcher(id INT) RETURNS varchar(100) NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE result varchar(100);
    IF id > 0 THEN
        SELECT readers.FIRSTNAME INTO result from readers WHERE READER_ID = id;
    ELSE
        SET result = 'The parameter has to be bigger than "0"!';
    END IF;
    RETURN result;
END $$
```

That gives me precisely what I wanted.